# Why use the chi-squared test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test

Consider the following problem:

You have 3 groups. Your null hypothesis is that the 3 groups are distributed uniformly. Your data consists of 90 observations. Under the null hypothesis we expect to observe 30 outcomes in each of the 3 groups. The actual data consists of the split 40/30/20. We would like to test our hypothesis and make a decision if we need to reject. The usual way is to approach this problem by calculating the chi-squared statistics:
$$ \chi^2 = \tfrac{(40-30)^2}{30} + \tfrac{(30-30)^2}{30} + \tfrac{(20-30)^2}{30} \approx 6.7 $$
Now we can calculate the $p$-value by looking this value up:

```
1 - pchisq(6.7, df = 2)
```

Therefore, the $p$-value is equal to approximately, 0.035.

---

There is an alternative method to solve this problem that is based on the principle that, "*just calculate the mean and variance, and then estimate it by a normal*". To be more specific, let $X$ be the random vector that describes the distribution of the 3 groups. Since our null hypothesis is a uniform distribution among the 3 groups we can say that,
$$ X \sim \text{Multinomial}(90, (\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{1}{3},\tfrac{1}{3}))$$
The mean of this random vector is equal to $(30,30,30)$. The (co)variance of $X$ is equal to,
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix} +20 & -10 & -10 \\ -10 & +20 & -10 \\ -10 & -10 & +20 \end{bmatrix} $$
(since the variance on the diagonal is $90\times \tfrac{1}{3}\times \tfrac{2}{3}$ and the covariance between the components is $-90\times \tfrac{1}{3}\times \tfrac{1}{3}$).

Thus, we can estimate the (distribution of) $X$ by a (multivariable) normal,
$$ X \sim \text{Normal}\left( (30,30,30), \Sigma \right) $$
The distance between the observed data $(40,30,20)$ and the expected data $(30,30,30)$ equates to $\sqrt{200}$.
We can now calculate the $p$-value by finding how rare is it for this normal to exceed a distance of greater than $\sqrt{200}$ from its mean?

```r
library(MASS)
count = 0 
for(n in 1:1e5){
sample = mvrnorm( 1, c(30,30,30), A )
if( sqrt( sum((sample - c(30,30,30))^2) ) < sqrt(200) ){
count = count + 1
}
}
1 - count/1e5
```

The above simulation produces a $p$-value of 0.036.

---

My question is what is the ***real*** benefit that we gain from using the $\chi$-squared statistic? The normal approximation approach is very intuitive and conceptually clearer.

The most obvious reply would be, "*because the $\chi$-squared approach is easier to implement*". That is only true because there is a standard $\chi$-squared calculator. We can, of course, develop our own calculator that uses this normal approximation instead.

Therefore, what would be a ***real*** benefit to using the $\chi$-squared? For instance, are there situations were the answers would be radically different?

Comment: It might be worth investigating power across a range of nulls (not just uniform nulls) and alternatives. The usual Pearson chi-squared should be asymptotically efficient, as would the G-test (and I think any other test of the Cressie-Read power-divergence family).